# Convert data type to text for case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

I need to convert data type to text for following statement. Can someone please help…

```
CASE WHEN [OrderID] IS NULL THEN 'N'
     WHEN [Order_ID] = '' THEN 'N'
     ELSE [Order_ID] END AS [Order_ID]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider `isnull()`

```
CASE WHEN isnull([OrderID], '') = '' THEN 'N'   
     ELSE cast([Order_ID] as varchar(300)) END AS [Order_ID]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for trying to help me but still I get the error (highiting "Then"), :  ,case
    when isnull([OrderID], '') = THEN 'N'
    else cast([OrderID] as varchar(300)) END AS
    [OrderID]

Comment: this should be `isnull([OrderID], '') = '' THEN`

Comment: I'm glad you found a useful answer. Please consider accepting the answer by clicking on the grey check mark to the left. It rewards the person who answered with some reputation points, and you get some, too

Answer (score 2):

Try casting the order ID to `varchar` in the `ELSE` branch of your `CASE` expression:

```
CASE WHEN COALESCE([Order_ID], '') = ''
     THEN 'N'
     ELSE CAST([Order_ID] AS VARCHAR(MAX)) END AS [Order_ID]
```

Comment: ,case
    when coalesce([Order_ID] is null) then 'N'
    when coalesce([Order_ID] = '') then 'N'
    else cast([Order_ID] as text
    end as [Order_ID]

Comment: What is `something` ?

Comment: Can you please see anything wrong with this:  ,case
    when COALESCE([Order_ID] is null) then 'N'
    when COALESCE([Order_ID] = '') then 'N'
    else CAST([Order_ID] AS TEXT)
    end as [Order_ID]

Comment: COALESCE :Evaluates the arguments in order and returns the current value of the first expression that initially doesn't evaluate to NULL. For example, SELECT COALESCE(NULL, NULL, 'third_value', 'fourth_value'); returns the third value because the third value is the first value that isn't null.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Alternate Method-

```
IIF(ISNULL([OrderID],'')='','N',CAST([OrderID] AS NVARCHAR(MAX))) AS [OrderID]
```

Comment: My data flow is:
Excel Template (Data Type:Number) Loading Table (column fdata type: Nvarchar(10) Table (Particular column formatted to data type: Nvarchar(10)
Template Data field contains only "Y" or "N" but by mistake this field has formatted to "Number" now we won't be able to do any changes to the template. My concern is if users put any numbers or any other characters SQL table should not accept it so that's why I want to convert data type to "Text". 
In your answer its convert to varchar(10), can you please advise me whether I should convert it to a "Text" field or "Varchar(10)?

Comment: TEXT is good:
If you need to store large texts in your database;If you do not search on the value of the column;If you select this column rarely and do not join on it.

VARCHAR is good:
If you store little strings;If you search on the string value;If you always select it or use it in joins.

Comment: Nvarchar stores UNICODE data. If you have requirements to store UNICODE or multilingual data, nvarchar is the choice. Varchar stores ASCII data and should be your data type of choice for normal use. so changed as NVARCHAR(MAX) instead of VARCHAR(100)

Answer (score 0):

---

You Can try below also :

```
CASE WHEN OrderID IS NULL THEN 'N'
          WHEN OrderID  ='' THEN 'N'
          ELSE convert(varchar(20),OrderID ) END
```